# visual composer vc_shortcodes-custom-css

Tags: visual-composer

We have found that visual composer is creating custom css class and css code is placed in:

```
<head>...</head>
```

We have shortcodes which generate some css code. we also want to make a custom css class and add the css code with the custom css class name.

We just want to make like this.

[image]
http://prntscr.com/ckw1pb

I can't find any develop documentation about it. can you please give us little details?

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty easy to figure it out, just use

```php
print_r($this)
```

on the `vc_row.php` template file of Visual Composer and it will reveal you everything.

The simplest way is to add this to your `vc_row.php` file:

```php
// Add this to your vc_row.php for separate custom css output
// Custom CSS
if(is_single() or is_archive() or is_404()) {
    if($css) {
        echo "<style>$css</style>";
    }
}
```